# Is there any way to log deleted messages with images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a message and image logger, but I have no thoughts about how I can log a message's image when the message is delete. 
I've tried to use `embed.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].url)`, but it didn't work and didn't cause any errors. The message text was logged but the image was not.
Also, I tried to use `embed.set_image(url=message.attachments)`, and obviously, it didn't work:`discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 BAD REQUEST (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.image.url: Not a well formed URL.`

````
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        timestamp=message.created_at,
        title = "[Message Deleted]",
        colour = discord.Colour(0xff0000)
        ) 
    embed.set_author(name=f'{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}', icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{message.author.id} • Message ID: {message.id}")
    embed.add_field(name="Message Content:", value=message.content)
    embed.set_image(url=message.attachments[0].url)
    channel = client.get_channel(665307525897519105)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    ```
````

Comment: I might be wrong here, but could it be that when a message with a picture is deleted, the deleted also gets deleted from Discord's servers and isn't recoverable? Edit: Yup I tested it, if you check an url from a deleted picture you get this: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/619998213881069628/665603524289363978/rem.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lu M is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693851/is-there-any-way-to-log-deleted-messages-with-pictures#comment105548132_59693851). There is not a good way to do this consistently after the message has already been deleted.

You've properly set the attachment URL as the embed's image URL, but if no one (besides Discord itself) viewed/requested the image, e.g. via a web browser, then when the message that the image is attached to is deleted, Discord's CDN will restrict access to the image.

Even if someone has viewed/requested the image already, the CDN will regularly delete/make inaccessible images that were attached to now deleted messages.